# Working with radius in Google Map Android API 2

Tags: android, google-maps, location, radius

Is it possible to show a message on my android application when a user is with a given radius of a location (latitude and longitude). I am using Google map API 2.

For example, given this latitude and longitude 40.218835, -74.000666, and if the user is within 10 kilometres radius of this location then I want a message to pop up saying “you are near watermark”. such as a toast displaying this message.

I have looked at some other posts on Stackoverflow and watched some tutorials on radius but I can't figure out how to get what I want.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You use Location Manager's [addProximityAlert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert(double,double,float,long,android.app.PendingIntent)) with [BroadcastReveiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

I will put some part of the code similar to what I worked on a while ago, it should give you the general idea of what to search for...

```
// IN SOME CLASS, YOU REGISTER BROADCAST RECEIVER FOR SOME COORDINATES
Intent thisIntent = new Intent("my.package.name.MyProximityReceiver"); // MyProximityReceiver is the name of the class where you extend BroadcastReceiver
Bundle thisBundle = new Bundle();
thisBundle.putString("placeName", "SomePlaceName");
thisIntent.putExtras(thisBundle);
PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0,
        thisIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locManager.addProximityAlert(40.218835,-74.000666, 
        10000 , -1, proximityIntent);  // 10000 is the 10km radius , -1 means no expiration, read more in the link provided above

// END OF THAT SOME CLASS YOU ARE REGISTERING BROADCASTRECEIVER IN


// CLASS MyProximityReceiver
public class MyProximityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

      public String placeName;

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

          Log.d("TAG_IN_BROADCAST", "In broadcast receiver");
          String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
          boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

          Bundle thisBundle = intent.getExtras();
          if (thisBundle != null)
          {
              placeName = thisBundle.getString("placeName");
          }

          if (entering)
          {
              Log.e("TAG_ENTERING","ENTERING");
              // SOMEONE ENTERED THE AREA
          }
          else
          {
              Log.e("TAG_LEAVING", "LEAVING");
              // SOMEONE EXITED THE AREA
          }
              ...
              ...
      }
      ....
}
```

This will probably not be working (these are only parts of the code), but this is just to get you the idea of how you can do things you desire...

Hope this helps...

Comment: Looks pretty confusing but nonetheless, I give it try and if it gets the job done, your the man!!!

Answer (score 0):

The technique you are looking for is geofencing. For official geofencing documentation on Google's website, please refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.html) document.

For a nice android tutorial on the same refer to [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-geofencing-google-maps) document.

Hope this Helps!!